# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable with if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've read over 50 posts with similar title, and have yet to answer my question.  What is wrong with my call to loop back to the start?  I'm using Python 2.7.7

```
def Skill():

    global PSkill
    global Fee

    Skill = input ("Please enter your skill level - you must either enter <C> for casual or <E> for expert!!")

    if Skill == "C" or Skill == "c":
        PSkill = "Casual"
        Fee = 30

    elif Skill == "E" or Skill == "e":
        PSkill = "Expert"
        Fee = 45

    else:
        print("Sorry I don't recognise that answer - please enter the answer again")
        Skill()
```

And further down i have this piece of code which won't work when their was an earlier error.

```
TotalFee = float(Rate) * float(Fee)
TotalFee = str(TotalFee)
```

The error which I then get is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 106, in <module>
Main()
line 93, in Main
Main()
line 68, in Main
Currency()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please fix your indentation and post the error message in full to assist anyone trying to answer your question!

Comment: `Skill()` is not a `function`... it's a `string`. Because you reused the name inside your function, you overwrote it's name.

Comment: @RaminNietzsche Looks like (s)he is in python 3

Answer (score 3):

You've redefined the symbol **Skill** within the function **Skill**.  Change the name of one of those.  For instance:

```
level = input ("Please enter your skill level - you must either enter <C> for casual or <E> for expert!!")

if level == "C" or level == "c":
    PSkill = "Casual"
    Fee = 30

elif level == "E" or level == "e":
    PSkill = "Expert"
    Fee = 45
```

Now, when you try to recur on **Skill**, that name still refers to the function, not the local variable.

---

Additional problem:

You should use a while loop to get input until you get a valid one.  Recursion adds garbage to the run-time stack.

```
level = ""
while level not in "CcEe":
    Skill = input ("Please enter your skill level - you must either enter <C> for casual or <E> for expert!!")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. By the way, I would use `level.upper() == "E"` instead of the `if level == "C" or level == "c":` and also use a `while-else` loop.

Comment: I would, too ... but I'm not here for a full code review, just trying to avoid a common problem on SO.